# CSS floating div?

Tags: css

This isn't that big of an issue but its been bugging me

I wanted the div in the center of the top of the page, but the code I have won't let it stay there when the user scrolls. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2B88C2;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    bottom:0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 55px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    position: top-fixed;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
    width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: It looks like some of your code is missing?  There is a closing } but not the opening one.

Comment: This is just a segment. This is the problem area. the rest has to do with other divs

Comment: it would be better if you posted all of the code otherwise we are guessing at the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing `position:fixed;`, `top:0;` and getting rid of `bottom:0;`. That should make it stay at the top, then all you have to do is center it.

Comment: Still isnt staying where it should be

Comment: Please post the rest of your code then and the HTML that it relates to, even a stripped down version is helpful because having context would help me answer.

Comment: You were actually right lol I just forgot the ; at the end of fixed.Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 3):

There is no 'top-fixed' - what you're going to need is

```
{
    position:fixed; 
    top:0;
    margin:0 auto
}
```

Comment: All 3 of you had the right answer lol was this really that easy?

Comment: There are thousands of people here, haha, it's GOING to be something that someone has dealt with before.